# Returning a PIN after a successful payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently trying to implement a mechanism whereby i can return a customer to a success page containing an activated PIN allowing access to a piece of software. The process is a straight forward PIN purchase without any kind of user accounts or login system involved.

I have the payment buttons and IPN script in place and working fine, but this only allows me to email the PIN after a successful payment via the IPN script, since of course the two sessions are completely separate to maintain security.

My problem with this is that i can't be sure the customer has access to the same email they used to pay with via Paypal. I had the idea of asking the user to enter which email they would like the PIN sent to prior to the Paypal redirection and then sending it as a custom value.. but then came visions of a mammoth backlog of support emails where users have entered the wrong email. I would really like to be able to redirect to a success page containing the PIN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).  The payer experience is very similar to standard payment buttons, however, the user is always guaranteed to return back to your site, so you can display whatever you want on your final page.

That documentation can be a little scary, but it's really just a matter of utilizing 3 API calls.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) - This is used to setup a new transaction and will return a token that you'll append to the end of a redirect URL to PayPal.  The user is sent to PayPal, they login and agree to pay, and are then sent back the ReturnURL that you specify in this request.
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) - Now back on your site/application, you use this API to obtain information about the buyer like their shipping address, address status, payer status, payer ID, etc. You will need the Payer ID for the final API call.
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) - This is very similar to the SetExpressCheckout request, but no transaction is completed until this call is completed.  Only then does the money move.

Again, those final calls are done on your site so you can use the API response data to update your database and display details on the final page however you want to.

Keep in mind that payments could still be pending for one reason or another, so you'll want to check the status (returned in the DECP response) and display appropriate information on the final page.

IPN's will still be triggered with Express Checkout so you can adjust the IPN script to handle pending payments or anything else you may want to automate outside the checkout flow.

If you happen to be working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make these calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Andrew. Yes i'm using PHP though i'm relatively new to it, so i think your class library will be a huge help. I'm currently in the process of digesting everything. As soon as i've successfully implemented it i'll let you know!